# VBA - Automation Error, server threw an exception, Lotus Notes Automation Code

Tags: vba, excel

I am at a loss as I have this program written in a different workbook, copying and pasting multiple objects and emailing them to a list of 100 people. I took the "automated emailing part" of the program and ran it fine for awhile, but it seems to throw a automation error about half through emailing to a list of 50 people.

Error Code is 
"Run-time error '-2147417851 (80010105)': 
Automation Error The Server threw an exception.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Send_HTML_Email()

Const ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT = 1729

'Send Lotus Notes email containing links to files on local computer

Dim NSession As Object      'NotesSession
Dim NDatabase As Object     'NotesDatabase
Dim NStream As Object       'NotesStream
Dim NDoc As Object          'NotesDocument
Dim NMIMEBody As Object     'NotesMIMEEntity
Dim SendTo As String
Dim subject As String
Dim HTML As String, HTMLbody As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lstrow As Long, j As Long
Dim RecpName As String, candiName As String
Dim a As Hyperlink

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Detail")

'  'Instantiate the Lotus Notes COM's Objects.


  lstrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For j = 3 To lstrow
 RecpName = ws.Cells(j, 2).Text
 candiName = ws.Cells(j, 1).Text

SendTo = RecpName
subject = wb.Worksheets("Email Settings").Range("B1").Text
Debug.Print subject

Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")       'using Lotus Notes Automation Classes (OLE)
Set NDatabase = NSession.GetDatabase("", "")

If Not NDatabase.IsOpen Then NDatabase.OPENMAIL

Set NStream = NSession.CreateStream

HTMLbody = "<p>" & "Hi " & ws.Cells(j, 2).Text & "," & "</p>" & _
     vbCrLf & _
    "<p>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(2, 2).Text & vbCrLf & _
      Sheets("Detail").Cells(j, 1).Text & "</p>" & vbCrLf & _
     "<p>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(3, 2).Text & _
     "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(4, 2).Text & _
       "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(5, 2).Text & _
       "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(6, 2).Text & "</p>" & _
      "<p>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(9, 2).Text & _
       "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(10, 2).Text & _
       "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(11, 2).Text & _
         "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(12, 2).Text & _
      "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(13, 2).Text & _
       "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(14, 2).Text & _
       "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(15, 2).Text & "</p>"

HTML = "<html>" & vbLf & _
        "<head>" & vbLf & _
        "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=UTF-8""/>" & vbLf & _
        "</head>" & vbLf & _
        "<body>" & vbLf & _
        HTMLbody & _
        "</body>" & vbLf & _
        "</html>"

NSession.ConvertMime = False     'Don't convert MIME to rich text

Set NDoc = NDatabase.CreateDocument()

With NDoc
    .Form = "Memo"
    .subject = subject
    .SendTo = Split(SendTo, ",")

    Set NMIMEBody = .CreateMIMEEntity
    NStream.WriteText HTML
    NMIMEBody.SetContentFromText NStream, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT

    .Send False
    .Save True, False, False
End With

NSession.ConvertMime = True      'Restore conversion

Set NDoc = Nothing
Set NSession = Nothing
     Next j
       MsgBox "The e-mail has successfully been created and distributed", vbInformation
        End Sub
```

Comment: This issue was never solved, I ended up realizing this Macro was somehow being blocked by something on my Managers laptop. Hopefully looking into this tomorrow to understand further as to why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have fixed this issue, The issue was at the beginning of the loop and end of the loop. I needed to Instantiate Lotus Objects before the loop started, and clear them out after the loop ended. Silly mistakes!

Comment: See OP comment for how I progressed on this VBA code, it ran perfectly, but something on another laptop was blocking it